# Laravel redirection errors in grouped route

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I configured the routes as follows:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@viewIndex')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/storage/user/pp/{user}/', 'StorageController@returnUserPicture');
    Route::get('/storage/user/download/{user}/{file}', 'StorageController@downloadUserFile');
    Route::get('/project/add', 'ProjectController@viewAddIndex')->name('/project/add');
    Route::post('/project/add', 'ProjectController@addProject')->name('/project/add');
    Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@viewIndex')->name('/projects');
    //... all the routes that I removed at this point
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@showUsers')->name('/users');
    Route::get('/logout', function(){
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    });
});
```

This is my `CheckAdminPrivileges` middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->rank >= 3)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('accessinformation')->with(...);
    }
}
```

When accessing `/` on the server without being logged in, the browser tells me the page was redirecting too many times. Let me describe what I actually want:

1. User accesses `/` of the domain (i.e. https://laravel.test.tld/)
2. User's not logged in? -> Redirect to `/login`
3. User's logged in? -> Redirect to `/dashboard` **ONLY IF** the user's an admin (i.e. `user`'s rank >= 3) **IF NOT THEN** redirect to `/accessinformation` with data so I can output to the user that they're not privileged to access the admin panel

In general, I want all the routes under the grouped Route to be accessible only by administrators, **IF USER NOT ADMIN THEN** redirect to `/accessinformation` with data so I can output to the user that they're not privileged to access this particular route (route's name etc is not important).

I already made a starting point with what I have, but apparently this isn't quite the trick since it still outputs redirection errors.

Looking forward to seeing solutions.

EDIT: Even deleting all the routes except `Auth::routes()` and clearing route's cache doesn't fix the main problem (page redirects too many times accessing `/`)

Comment: Logout and login routes are already defined in Auth::routes(); try deleting that inside your route group.

Comment: @TahaPaksu doesn't address the problem

Comment: Can you show us `viewIndex` on your DashboardController.php